# Azure Logic Apps HTTP Unauthorized

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to call a SuccessFactors API to update some data from a Logic App.
But I keep running into an "Unauthorized" error.

[image: error]

How can I get some more details about this error? Can't see input-output for this action so it's a bit difficult.

Kind Regards
Tim

Comment: You can check the Run History, but...."Unauthorized" typically *is the error*.  Are you absolutely sure the auth parameters for the call are all correctly set?

Comment: I'm quite sure yes. Copied it from some tests I did with Postman and did a test with RequestBin. I just want to check if there are any more details in the actual response.

Comment: If there's anything, it would be in the Run History but don't expect too much.  Auth errors typically don't return any detail to not facilitate miscreant behavior.

Comment: you are able to make a succesful postman request? can you show us that request?

Comment: I found my issue. SuccessFactors has some settings on user level to only allow logins for certain ip's. If I add the logic app IP's, it works.

Comment: @TimD'haeyer, Glad to see that:) You could write the solution as an reply to close this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up trying to mimic the call in an online REST test tool. That gave me the error I was looking for.
SuccessFactors has some settings on user level to only allow logins for certain ip's. If I add the logic app IP's, it works.

Comment: where is this setting exactly where we need to add ?